# Blackberry OS 7

Tags: blackberry

I have an App. that was built for BB OS 6. Wanted to know if it will work on the new OS 7 without any glitches.
If not, can it be ported without re-doing the entire thing.

Answer (score 1):

It will work but as the devices probably will have different resolutions maybe you will have to made some code changes so de fields adapt better to the screen even if the code behave dinamically.

You can see it if you try your app in the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It will work without making any changes, as Blackberry 7 has backward compatibility for the builds.  You might get some regulations issues, if your program is coded to behave dynamically then no issues.

Also, You don't really need to build again. Just go ahead and install on Blackberry 7. It will work.